# Generate csv file for values stored in variables - Javascript and Nodejs module

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, csv, export-to-csv

I have variables as below which stores values. I want this variables to be stored as Key:Value in csv file. Need your help in doing this with javascript or node module

```
Example:
var name = "Alex"
var Age = 25
```

CSV file should have Ouptut like this:

```
name,Age
Alex,25
```

Comment: convert JSON to CSV format

Answer (score 2):

You can use object like:

```js
var data = {
  name: "Alex",
  Age: 25,
};

var output = [
  Object.keys(data).join(','),
  Object.values(data).join(',')
].join('\n');

console.log(output);
```

Comment: I am getting error like this... Object.values is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Demo - Covnert JSON to CSV</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/raw/master/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // JSON to CSV Converter
        function ConvertToCSV(objArray) {
            var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
            var str = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                var line = '';
                for (var index in array[i]) {
                    if (line != '') line += ','

                    line += array[i][index];
                }

                str += line + '\r\n';
            }

            return str;
        }

        // Example
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // Create Object
            var items = [
                  { name: "Item 1", color: "Green", size: "X-Large" },
                  { name: "Item 2", color: "Green", size: "X-Large" },
                  { name: "Item 3", color: "Green", size: "X-Large" }];

            // Convert Object to JSON
            var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(items);

            // Display JSON
            $('#json').text(jsonObject);

            // Convert JSON to CSV & Display CSV
            $('#csv').text(ConvertToCSV(jsonObject));
        });
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>
        JSON</h1>
    <pre id="json"></pre>
    <h1>
        CSV</h1>
    <pre id="csv"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```